# linked list - create the nodes dynamically or statically?

Tags: c++

When I create a list class, what would be more programmatically correct - create the nodes dynamically or statically?

```
#include "List.h"

istream & operator>>(istream & is, List & _list)    
{
    int value1,value2;

    is >> value1;

    _list.head = new List::Link(value1, NULL);//Creating a link in the list with the value1, the "head" of the list points to it
    List::Link*p = _list.head;//Auxiliary pointer that is currently points to "head"

    is >> value2;

    while (value1<value2)//Sorted list in ascending order    
    {
        p->next= new List::Link(value2, NULL);//the "next" of 'p' pointes to link with valuse2

        value1 = value2;//Last value Typed. 

        p = p->next;//Pointer promotion

        is >> value2;    
    }

    return is;
}
```

Comment: C does not have classes. I guess this is C++. Please update the tag if that is indeed the case.

Comment: In C++ the more "programmatically correct" thing is to use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and skip all of this. Why is the `>>` operator adding things on? By convention that should be `<<` to append (e.g. `push`) and `>>` to remove (e.g. `pop`).

Comment: Tip: Use `nullptr` in preference to `NULL` for pointers. Also try and anchor things like `&` to one of the type or the variable name, but don't leave it hanging. That is `istream& is` and `istream &is` are both common conventions. `istream & is` is not.

Comment: After formatting the code I see you're using this to read in from an `istream` so `>>` makes more sense, but still not a lot of sense since this reads two entries at once. It should read one at a time.

Comment: How could you create a list nodes statically if you don't know the list contents at compile time?

Comment: What does "statically" means? Describe what you want to achieve.